# Should functions within React functional components be wrapped?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component that has one function within it, `renderMessages`.

```
const MessageContainer = (props) => {
     const renderMessages = () => {
        return props.messages.map((message, index) => {
            return(
                <Message
                    key={index}
                    username={message.username}
                    message={message.message}
                    fromCurrentUser={message.fromCurrentUser}
            />);
        })
    }

     return(
          <div className='messages'>
               {renderMessages()}
          </div>
     )

}
```

However, I realized that instead of wrapping renderMessages function on the map, I can just have:

```
const renderMessages = props.messages.map((message, index) => {
     return(
          <Message
               key={index}
               username={message.username}
               message={message.message}
               fromCurrentUser={message.fromCurrentUser}
            />);
      })
}
```

And as a result, my final return would just contain

```
return(
     <div className='messages'>
          {renderMessages}
     </div>
)
```

In a class-based component and within a render function, I'd use the last of the two. Which of the two is considered the best practice when using functional components, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

> Which of the two is considered the best practice when using functional components, and why?

Best practices change with context - e.g. the team you're working on - so this is an opinion-based question out of the gate.

That being said, in my opinion, I wouldn't do either. I'd do (and I do) this:

```
const MessageContainer = (props) => {


     return (
          <div className='messages'>
            {props.messages.map((message, index) => (
                  <Message
                      key={index}
                      username={message.username}
                      message={message.message}
                      fromCurrentUser={message.fromCurrentUser}
                  />
             ))}
          </div>
     )

}
```

What's the purpose of the extra variable anyway?

While you're at it, [don't use indexes for keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

The dirty secret about all those extra methods you stuck on your class components that encapsulated rendering logic is that they were an anti-pattern - those methods were, in fact, components.

EDIT #2

As pointed out in the other answer, the most performant solution for this specific use case is specifying the map function outside the functional component:

```
const renderMessage = (message,index) => (
  <Message
   key={index}
   {...message}
  />
)

const MessageContainer = (props) => {
  return (
   <div classname='messages'>
     {props.messages.map(renderMessage)}
   </div>
  );
}
```

But, you shouldn't prematurely optimize and I would advocate for the original solution I posted purely for simplicity/readability (but, to each their own).

Answer (score 0):

Good job separating the mapping outside the component's return, because this way you'll be only calling the same function over and over again untill the .map is done iterating, but if you wrote it in the component's return, every time the .map iterate over the next item you'll be creating a new function.
Regarding the question, I'd recommend the second way, clean/readable code is always preferable.

P.S. try to use the unique message id instead of the index.

Comment: Why would using a variable vs inlining the exact same code into the return statement change the semantics of ‘map’?

Comment: not the semantic of 'map', but the function itself, mostly you should declare functions outside of the component's return so you declare them only once and always reuse the same reference. When you declare the function inside, every time the component is rendered the function will be defined again. So; if the page is rerendering 3 times, you'll have to declare a new anon function 3 times, but if you declared it outside, you will call the same function 3 times, so in comparison, it's better to have 1 reference than redeclaring a new function every time under the hood.

Comment: Ok, fully agreed. That's nitpicky performance that's not likely to be an issue in most of the real world, but still valid. If you look closely, however, the OP didn't separate it from the return statement as `renderMessages` uses `**props**.messages.map` - so it's still inside the functional component. The question is actually about making it a callable function inside the component versus just assigning the result to a variable.

Comment: It's inside the functional component, not its return statement.
real-world projects are 100+ components, so whenever we work on real-world projects, we need to make functions centralized, reusable, readable, and easy to debug, plus that we have to squeeze every millisecond of our code.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you understand that the two options being discussed: putting it inside the body of the functional component and assigning it to a variable vs putting it directly inside the return statement are 100% equivalent.